# Is it ok to generate a new .ssh keypair for root user if I can't find an existing one?

Tags: ssh

If I generate a new ssh keypair for the root user, with

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

am I running the risk of overwriting any existing ones? I need to add one to my gitlab account so I can clone a repo onto a client's server to deploy a site. I have looked for existing ones, but

```
ls ~/.ssh
```

only returns a known_hosts file. So I figured I would generate a temporary one and add it my account, then remove it afterwards. Does this sound like an ok thing to do? I want to be sure I won't interfere with any existing credentials they have set up.

Comment: Why not? You can even have a bunch of keypairs each with specific parameters. One without password for scripts, passworded 1024 bits for connection from secure environment, and third, passworded 16k - for use in the hostile circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"am I running the risk of overwriting any existing ones? "**

Yes but ssh-keygen asks the "file in which to save the key".

**"I want to be sure I won't interfere with any existing credentials they have set up"**

Then specify alternative key file.

```
> ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa): ^C
```